# IIS 7.5 fake 404 error with 'aux' path

Tags: iis, error-handling

Anyone know how to prevent this IIS7.5 /aux path issue (work on IIS8). this is not a real 404 error !?! ex http://msdn.microsoft.com/aux

Comment: Never heard of this before. FWIW, I tried a bunch of DOS reserved filenames (e.g., NUL, PRN, LPT1, COM1...) all exhibit the same behavior. But I guess I'm missing the point. What is the problem?

Comment: the error is not managed by customerrors setting thus sending too verbose response headers, enabling eventual attackers to get unwanted information from the server. thanks for your inquery

Comment: Off the top of my head, I'd consider URL Rewriting, and direct each of the MS-DOS reserved filenames to your 404 page.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to some built-in restrictions on URLs in IIS, which do not allow you to use names that have special meanings in the Windows file system, dating back all the way to the days of CP/M:
https://www.bitquabit.com/post/zombie-operating-systems-and-aspnet-mvc/

If you are using ASP.NET version 4 or later, you can use this setting in `web.config` to disable these URL restrictions:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true"/>

    <!-- ... your other settings ... -->
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This should be safe if you are sure there are is no direct mapping between parts of URLs and file system paths being done anywhere, in the web server, the framework or your own code and any third-party dependencies. This should usually be the case in a modern web application, but don't take my (or anyone's) word for it, unless they have solid proof, which I cannot provide here.

See also: http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/29/allowing-reserved-filenames-in-URLs.aspx

Comment: Can you please summarize the answer and use the link as a reference to additional information rather than the answer itself? Additionally if this solved your problem, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you are dealing with problems like this, it may mean that your application uses arbitrary text in the URL path that may be originally user input. This is a misguided design pattern used in so-called "REST" APIs in order to make URLs "pretty". You will probably also run into issues with percent-encoding, Unicode characters, trans-BNP Unicode characters (emoji!), Unicode normalization, case-insensitivity (along with the Turkish-i and Greek-something problem) and countless issues that are yet to be discovered.

REST is not about pretty URLs, and pretty URLs do not need to contain arbitrary text (and unless you are Wikipedia, you will have a hard time getting it right). Pretty URLs improving your Google ranking is controversial at best, if not a myth.

Here are some suggestions to redesign the URLs in your application:

1. Use unique IDs instead of names. Human-readable names should never be used as identifiers ever.
2. If you think you have to decorate your URLs with text (in addition to a unique ID), then "sanitize" the text part. For example, you can remove any non-ASCII characters and any characters with special meanings in URLs, whitespaces, etc., and replace sequences of disallowed characters with dashes. And of course, also replace the  "forbidden" names such as `aux`. But, seriously, don't bother with "prettifying" URLs like this.
3. If it makes sense for your application, let the user specify the URL fragment, but use validation to limit what URLs are allowed. You can then enforce the fragment to be unique and use it as a unique ID, rather than just decoration.
4. If `aux` is a fixed part of your URLs, just replace it with something else.
5. Use query strings or POST requests for arbitrary user input. And of course, validate and sanitize it. Something like a search string should not be in the URL path.
6. If you disagree, or you have no choice in the matter, or no time to redesign your API, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14771755/2279059